# Using Neo4jclient to search for property with regex

Tags: cypher, neo4jclient

I have a working cypher query but can't get it to work in Neo4jclient.

My cypher query is

```
start n=node(*) where has(n.Name) and n.Name =~ 'X.*' return n;
```

which returns all nodes with a Name property which starts with X.
I am on purpose not using indices or relations here.

My first childish attempt (not even using regex I plan to use) fails with timeout(!) on res.Results

```
var res = _client.RootNode
    .StartCypher("n")
    .Where<Meeting>(m => m.Name == "X")
    .Return<Meeting>("m");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var query = _client.Cypher
    .Start("n", graphClient.RootNode)
    .Where("has(n.Name)")
    .And()
    .Where("n.Name =~ 'X.*'")
    .Return<Meeting>("n");
```

This worked on my machine, you'll get the results like:

```
var results = query.Results;
```

**Edit:**
I think I've realised why yours had problems, in the beginning, you put `StartCypher("n")` and subsequently, use `m` instead of `n`. So `Return<Meeting>("m")` should be `Return<Meeting>("n")`

Comment: Thankyou. I'd like to set mark your answer as Answer but I still get timeout. Is it something with neo4jclient that fails? (I just updated and changed And().Where("n... to AndWhere("n... but to no avail.

Comment: I have traced query.Query.QueryText and it works alright in the web admin ui. But through neo4jclient i get a timeout.

Comment: I don't know of a reason you'd be getting a timeout, does the query take a while in the console?

Comment: Nope. No time at all. Well... 21ms when n=node(*) and 1ms when n=node(=) but I consider it as no time at all.

Comment: Is there any way to trace what is coming to Neo4j? A sniffer come to think of it.

Comment: If you run Fiddler you can see all the network travel. You will probably need to change any connection in your code to '127.0.0.1' to be '127.0.0.1.' for fiddler to pick it up. If you are using DNS names, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: You can inspect the Cypher query like this:
 var text = query.Query.QueryText;
var params = query.Query.QueryParameters;

More info here: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher